# Quality metrics and continuous integration for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, hudson, sonarqube

In my day work, I work on your classic Java aplication. We use as "software factory" : Maven, Hudson and Sonar.

In my night work, I work on personnal ruby on rails stuff. I have a certain number of applications, not much known but that's not my question. My question is :

Is there tool like Hudson - Sonar for ruby on rails ? Bundle and gemfiles do the maven job, but is there anything out there to do the hudson and sonar job ? For me, it's summed up to this 2 :
 - build and run tests on commit
 - build quality metrics and code statistics on demand

Regards to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hudson will do the trick.

We use the Hudson [Rake plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Rake+Plugin) and [Ruby metrics plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Ruby+Metrics+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

We use Hudson for building a Rails 3 project which is hosted on Github.

We have setup RVM, Bundler, Rspec, Cucumber, Xvfb (for headless browser based features), Xvnc (for watching the build remotely).

The build runs on on HCPU XLARGE EC2 slaves running Ubuntu 10.04 spawned with Hudson's EC2 plugin. We use [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) gem to parallelize our specs and cucumber features to utilize all available cores and memory. This has helped us bring a monster ~35 min single threaded build down to ~6 mins.

As for the metrics, we have a Hudson job which runs a metrics build using [metric_fu](http://metric-fu.rubyforge.org/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for sonar : found an outdated one : https://github.com/pica/ruby-sonar-plugin